# While loop which breaks if a keyboard code is entered

Tags: java, keyboard

I have a while loop which is monitoring a database to see if a boolean value changes.
I want this while loop to break and stop monitoring the database if code a is entered locally , i.e:

1. While loop is running.
2. User enters a code on the keyboard (e.g. "0011545454") and hits return.
3. Separate method runs, then while loop resumes.

The code is a 10 character integer and the first digit is always a 0.
I've tried variations of the following to detect if something has been typed:

```
if (KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED > -1) {
```

...however the if statement runs, even if I haven't typed anything.

The program runs in the console. Anyone have any ideas how to solve this problem?
Also how do I use the KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED to detect the zero (0) character?

Comment: The database represents a door's locked state. If the door is locked a user can still unlock the door by entering a code on that machine which is why I need both to happen at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

[KeyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#KEY_TYPED) is a constant identifier, not a keycode the user has input.  KeyEvent's constant value is 400, meaning your check will always pass.

If you're monitoring a database for a boolean value change, don't look at the user's input.  Query the database itself periodically to see if the boolean value changes.